# Canvas doesn't show up in the browser using-fillRect

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm a beginner and I just learning about Canvas. I try this but doesn't work with me. this the code I used. Where is the problem ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> 28 - Canvas - Create Simple Canvas </title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="Canvas - Create Simple Canvas" >
  <style>
    canvas{
      width: 800px;
      height: 400px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      margin: 50px auto;
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <canvas id="c">  </canvas>
  <script>

  var MyCanvas = document.getElementById('c');

  myContext = MyCanvas.getContext('2d');
  myContext.fillStyle = '#080';
  myContext.fillRect('0, 0, 100, 50');

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

the Console give me that : **Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'fillRect' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': 4 arguments required, but only 1 present.**

Comment: Remove the quotes from your parameters. fillRect() takes multiple parameters, not one parameter string.

Comment: thanks a lot the problem is fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open your html file in Chrome and then open Chrome Developer tools (F12 on Windows) it will help you to debug your application. The console tab in dev tools will output any JavaScript errors on screen can tell you where the error in your code is. So for example, from your code above I got the follow error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'fillRect' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': 4 arguments required, but only 1 present.
    at index.html:26`

Based on this I looked at the fillRect method and noticed that you're passing in the arguments as a string. If I look at [fillRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillRect) on MDN it tells me that it's expecting 4 numeric arguments which is what the error also says. So I changed line 26 `myContext.fillRect('0, 0, 100, 50');` to 
`myContext.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 50);` by removing the surrounding quotes
and it worked.

Following this pattern will help you debug your code.

Comment: thanks a lot good explaination

Answer (score 0):

the parameter of fillRect is not a string.

You can simple set the values like the code below.

make   myContext.fillRect('0, 0, 100, 50');
to

myContext.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 50);

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> 28 - Canvas - Create Simple Canvas </title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="Canvas - Create Simple Canvas" >
  <style>
    canvas{
      width: 800px;
      height: 400px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      margin: 50px auto;
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <canvas id="c">  </canvas>
  <script>

  var MyCanvas = document.getElementById('c');

  myContext = MyCanvas.getContext('2d');
  myContext.fillStyle = '#080';
  myContext.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 50);

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your help the problem is fixed